# Erro: The requested client requires the gRPC extension | gRPC + App Engine + Firestorm

Tags: php, google-app-engine, firestore

Bom dia, estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que vai receber dados via post e vai inserir em um banco de dados firebase/firestore, local eu consegui fazer rodar com sucesso, mas quando subo para o ambiente do google (App Engine) ele da o seguinte erro.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\GoogleException: The requested client requires the gRPC extension. Please see https://cloud.google.com/php/grpc for installation instructions. in /srv/vendor/google/cloud/Core/src/ClientTrait.php:75 Stack trace: #0 /srv/vendor/google/cloud/Firestore/src/FirestoreClient.php(137): Google\Cloud\Firestore\FirestoreClient->requireGrpc() #1 /srv/index.php(11): Google\Cloud\Firestore\FirestoreClient->__construct(Array) #2 {main} thrown in /srv/vendor/google/cloud/Core/src/ClientTrait.php on line 75
```

Eu consegui instalar a gRPC local mas não encontro como habilitar lá no meu app engine.

Se alguém tiver uma luz...

desde já agradeço!

Answer (score 0):

Create a php.ini file in se same place of your index.php file exist and add this code inside of php.ini:

`; enable the gRPC extension
extension=grpc.so
; for debugging purposes only
display_errors=On`